# Dynamically setting up IN condition (With Integers) in PIVOT statement (GBQ)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What if I want to run the following PIVOT process

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
Customer,
Age,
FROM customer_table
)
PIVOT
(
-- #2 aggregate
COUNT(*) AS Count_Ages
-- #3 pivot_column
FOR Age in (15, 45, 65)
)
```

but where I define dynamically the Ages as follows

```
FOR Age IN (SELECT Age FROM ages_table)
```

What is the easier way to do it in a clean way? Taking into account that Age is an Integer column.

Comment: What database are you using ?

Comment: It is GBQ, I added it in the title now.

Comment: you can't , you need to provide sample data and desuired output

Comment: U cannot. You have to hardcode the values inside IN clause